# A function to graph the sum of distance to different coordinates.

Tags: graphing-functions, coordinate-systems

If I have three or more different points on a coordinate plane, is there a way to graph all the points where the sum of the distance to these three points is equal to a specific number.

For example, if I have point A (-5,0), point B (7,0) , and point C (1,4).   How can I graph all the points whose distances to the original three points will sum up to a total of 14.  I imagine it would look like semi circle above (1,0) but I don't know how to write it as a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P = (x,y)$ be a point satisfying this relationship.

The distance from $A$ to $P$ is $\sqrt{(x-(-5))^2 + (y-0)^2}$. If you can do the same for $B$ to $P$ and $C$ to $P$, your equation is just:

$$AP + BP + CP = 14$$

As it turns out, no point exists such that the sum of the distances is $14$. The minimum distance for a point to exist is around $14.3924766$ ([Desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jifuvldjla)).

Comment: What is the  point of triangle with minimum distance sum called?

Comment: [Fermat point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point).

Comment: Thanks. It has three $ 120^{\circ}  $ vertices at the Fermat point.

Answer (score 1):

If your $3$ points are $A(x_1,y_1), B(x_2,y_2), C(x_3,y_3)$, the point where you want to get the distance from is $(x,y)$ and the sum of the distances is $S$, then the function you're looking for is

$$\sqrt{(x - x_1)^2 + (y - y_1)^2} + \sqrt{(x - x_2)^2 + (y - y_2)^2} + \sqrt{(x - x_3)^2 + (y - y_3)^2} = S \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

With your particular example of $A(-5,0), B(7,0), C(1,4)$, you would get, for them to add up to $14$, that

$$\sqrt{(x + 5)^2 + (y - 0)^2} + \sqrt{(x - 7)^2 + (y - 0)^2} + \sqrt{(x - 1)^2 + (y - 4)^2} = 14 \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

With the $y_1$ and $y_2$ co-ordinates being $0$, this can be simplified to

$$\sqrt{(x + 5)^2 + y^2} + \sqrt{(x - 7)^2 + y^2} + \sqrt{(x - 1)^2 + (y - 4)^2} = 14 \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

Comment: Hold on... you don't know $y = 0$ so you cannot simplify into the last line.

Comment: @TobyMak Thanks for pointing that out. I just realized the same thing, so I've just correct the result.

Comment: In a three body problem  if the sum of distances is less than distance between fixed points there can be no locus or dynamics motion. Also there are limits of existence in  restricted three/four body problems (see Wiki) for planetary motion involving Lagrange points.etc.